# Best way to debug JavaScript code with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

How can i debug JavaScript code in Visual Studio 2010 with MVC Razor projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is ran in the browser rather than on the server, so it depends on which browser you're testing in.  See this question:

[How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: I want to debug in Visual Studio rather than the browser

Comment: I recommend Firefox plus Firebug

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't run the JavaScript.  So it can't debug the JavaScript.  You have to do it in a browser.

Comment: If there's a one thing I'd take with me if I was shipwrecked on an island that would be Firebug.